# git - getting a branch to mimic master branch

Tags: git, github

I have a [repository on github](https://github.com/nhoss2/jekyll-bootstrap) where I want any changes on the master branch to be automatically copied to the `gh-pages` branch.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need two identical branches? If it's just a matter of branch name then you can work on `gh-pages` branch and forget about `master` at all. It's a convention to have main branch of the repo named `master` but you can rename it if you need a different name.

Comment: I deleted the master branch, but how do i push the changes to the remote repository, it just says `everything up to date` when i do a git push

Comment: Are you using `gh-pages` or `master` branch locally?

Comment: ok never mind, `git push origin :master` does the trick. this is useful: http://matthew-brett.github.com/pydagogue/gh_delete_master.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see a more straightforward solution, but assuming you have a server you could just pull, merge and then push back automatically. You can setup a scheduled repeating task or use [a post-receive hook](http://help.github.com/post-receive-hooks/).